# Hardware Load-Balancer for JBoss

Tags: apache, jboss

In what scenario does it make sense to put a hardware load-balancer in front of the apache servers that are running mod_cluster? Logically it seems like mod_cluster is doing all the load balancing. Is mod_cluster required if you're doing Jboss clustering?

Example Architecture
(1) website www.foo.bar being served from: 
(4) Apache Servers Running mod_cluster
(2) JBoss App Servers - 1 Cluster

Comment: If you cluster with JBoss, you do not have to loadbalance with mod_cluster...You could use mod_jk, mod_proxy, or another software or hardware loadbalancer

Answer (score 2):

Benefits of a load balancer:

- If one server goes down, some use heartbeats and then do not send traffic to dead servers
  Downsides of clustering:
- In clustering, if a component breaks down, it kills every server.

Benefits of a cluster:

- More power to serve webpages
- All on one disk

Downsides of a load balancer:

- Costly hardware (or free software)
- If the load balancer dies, everything dies.

Feel free to add to this answer.